# In Ruby how can I check if a symbol is in an array of symbols?

Tags: ruby

Can I do the following? If so how?

I have an array of symbols

```
symbols = %w{:sym1 :sym2 :sym3} # is this correct implementation?

# I'm putting this in a function for this illustration
def check_symbol(symbol)
  symbols.include?(symbol)
end

puts check_symbol(:sym1) # expect true, but I get false
puts check_symbol(:sym44) # expect false of course
```

How can I do so I get true on the first puts statement?

Comment: The answer by @eugen is correct, but you've also got a typo in your method. Should be `symbols.include?(symbol)`.

Comment: Stepping through your code in IRB would have shown you that `symbols` is an array of strings, not symbols. You should get into the habit of verifying your assumptions as part of preparing to ask for help with code, your coworkers will greatly appreciate this.

Comment: Yes I used irb and saw it as an array of string, hence I asked the question. Now I know what %i{...} is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify an array of symbols as `%i[ ... ]`.

And to check if your symbols is in an array of symbols you could use all? to check if all they respond with true to `.is_a?(Symbol)` and then if the array includes your specific one, like:

```
array_of_symbols = %i[sym1 sym2 sym3]
p array_of_symbols.all? { |e| e.is_a?(Symbol) } && array_of_symbols.include?(:sym1)
# true
```

---

Nowadays you can skip the block for `all?` (or similar; `none?`, `one?`, `any?`) and pass just the class you're testing for;

```
[:foo, 'foo', 1].all?(Symbol)
# => false
[:foo, :bar].all?(Symbol)
# => true
```

Comment: Also known as [Ruby percent notation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation).

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an array of symbols, what you have is an array of strings that look like symbols.
The correct definition would be

`symbols = %i{sym1 sym2 sym3}`